# Parse multiple string as single variable in Shell

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose I have files containing below string.

```
Paris, France baguette
Madrid, Spain callos
Sheffield, England steak
```

I want to loop through the files, printing City and culinary.

```
City: Paris, France
Food: baguette
```

The tricky part is there is a space between Country and its City, obviously simple `while read -r` doesn't work because of the whitespace.

Comment: `while read` works on your example: `while read -r city country culinary; do printf 'City: %s %s\nFood: %s\n' "$city" "$country" "$culinary"; done < file`.

Comment: That might be impossible: for example when you have a `London, Great Britain fish & chips`. Your file format is broken, you should change it to something unambiguous

Comment: Yeah, I decided to insert a delimiter between data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an other delimiter between country and food
for example ","

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt"|xargs -I {} sh -c "awk -F, '{print \"City: \" \$1 \",\" \$2; nexline; print \"Food: \"\$3}' {}"

City: London, Great Britain
Food: fish & chips
City: Paris, France
Food: baguette
City: Madrid, Spain
Food: callos
City: Sheffield, England
Food: steak
```